# How does this UHF antenna works?

Tags: antenna, rfid

I have a cheap UHF RFID antenna (9dB) like this :

[image: My antenna]

How does this kind of antenna work?
There is no dipole? Why does the "L" at the bottom left of the disc have finer passages than others? I can not find any information on the web about this type of antenna and the physical rules used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a circularly polarized antenna. The central disc is fed at two points at 90° from each other; furthermore, these two feed points have different lengths of transmission line from the connector. You'll find that the difference in lengths corresponds to a 90° phase shift at the operating frequency.

Two fields at 90° to each other, fed with a phase shift of 90°, combine to create a radio wave whose polarization rotates at it propagates away from the face of the disc. This is called circular polarization.

Comment: Thank you, great answer! Just an extra question, is it possible to reverse the polarization?

Comment: You'd have to swap the lengths of the transmission lines, which, given the fact that it's all stamped from a single piece of metal, would not be easy.

Comment: There might be a "cheat" you could use -- a mirror image of a left-circular wave is right-circular. So -- I theorize -- if you put a metal plate (insulated from the antenna and everything else) at an angle across the face of the antenna like a mirror, it should both change the direction of the signal (as you'd expect) and also reverse the polarization.

Can someone who knows more about antennas tell me if I'm right?